# Using node reference question

Tags: nodes

In Drupal-6 I have a content type called: **Colors** with the following fields: **title**, **body** and **code**.
Then I have another content type called: **Material** with the following fields: **title**, **body** and **color**. This **color** field is a **node reference** related to the Colors content type.

So far so good.

Now when I create a **Material** node I can select a color from a select list. And here is my issue: this select list shows the **title** of the colors nodes. Is there any way to show the **code** for the node instead of the **title**. Or better, show the **title** and the **code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a view to show the nodes that can be referenced, have a look at the settings of the widget, it's been a while since I used D6, but if you select title and code inside your view it should be visible when you edit a Material node.

Comment: I don´t understand I have a content type with a field to  reference to another content type. How do I implement views here??

Comment: you create a new view (http://drupal.org/project/views) that lists your colors. In the settings of your node reference field instead of selecting the content type(s) that can be referenced, you select this view